# Since last update I have annoying problem with scrolling on touchpad 16.04

Tags: 16.04, thinkpad, multi-touch, synaptics, scrolling

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on ThinkPad T440s and since last Update (which was also the first after installing this version), I'm experiencing annoying "jump-to-up"s when I try to scroll with two fingers on the touchpad (I don't have a mouse, so I haven't tried it with mouse). Explained exactly, It happens when I scroll down, remove my 2 fingers and put it again on top of touchpad to scroll down further, then it scroll to top or just one page up! I thought first it's a chrome issue (because at the same time it's updated to the version 51.0.2704.84) then I recognized it happens outside chrome too… It happens just sometimes and some other times everything goes smooth)! I searched a bit and found nothing similar to this… so I try to ask here before I report it as a bug.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thinkpad T460P: Scrolling jumps to top on 2 finger touch](http://askubuntu.com/questions/797057/thinkpad-t460p-scrolling-jumps-to-top-on-2-finger-touch)

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the same issue, this helped me:

```
id=$(xinput --list --id-only 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad')
xinput --set-prop $id 'Synaptics Edge Scrolling' 0 0 1
```

Comment: What does this command do? Can you please [edit] your answer so that we're not blindly running commands here?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You might be able to improve this answer with providing the steps needed in more detail to make it a rock solid answer.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. My workaround was to install xserver-xorg-input-libinput and remove the relevant synaptic configuration:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-libinput
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-synaptics-t440s.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-synaptics-t440s.conf.backup
```

Comment: The solution is correct, but the second command won't work, because there is no `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-synaptics-t440s.conf` file.

Comment: Maybe there is another file matching etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/*synaptics*.conf which is no longer needed. Otherwise omit the second command